# How can you change the value of the iterating variable in a loop in Python?

Tags: python

I have something like this :

```
#tokens is a list of a few words
for i in xrange(0,len(tokens)):
    #some code to modify the contents of token[i]
    if tokens[i] == some value:
        del tokens[i]
```

Now if the array has 7 elements, i goes from 0 to 6, and in the middle of the processing if I delete an array element, then the new size becomes 6 but the loop will still run till i=6 and access tokens[6] and throw an error because the new size is 6 i.e. max index is 5.

I guess I can use a while loop with some condition like:

```
while(i<currMaxIndex)
```

where I can dynamically change currMaxIndex.

But I was just really curious to know if there was any way to alter i in the for loop itself.

If absolutely MUST know, this is my code:

```
for i in xrange(0,len(tokens)):
            tokens[i]=tokens[i].translate(string.maketrans("",""),string.punctuation)
            if tokens[i]=='':
                del tokens[i]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this:

```
def myfilter(token):
    return token.translate(None, string.punctuation)   

tokens = filter(None, map(myfilter, tokens))
```

If the logic is too complicated to do it through the map / filter, it is recommended to use this approach:

```
for item in items[:]: # [:] copies the list
    if condition(item):
        items.remove(item)
```

Comment: This is sort of heave computationally right? With the [:] copying the entire list?

Answer (score 2):

`len(tokens)` is computed when you create the `xrange` object, so if you are deleting elements from the list, `tokens[i]` may not exist or may have a value that is different from what you'd expect.

For example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a[1]
2
>>> del a[1]
>>> a[1]
3
```

Instead of modifying the original list, create a new one:

```
new_tokens = []

for token in tokens:
    translated = token.translate(None, string.punctuation)

    if translated:
        new_tokens.append(translated)
```

Or you can `filter` a generator expression:

```
new_tokens = filter(None, (token.translate(None, string.punctuation) for token in tokens))
```